# Pandas InvalidIndexError during multiple assignment using at

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I used to rely on `pandas` `at` for multiple assignment in the following way:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [2, 4, 1, 5, 56, 6, 1, 2, 1, 0], 
                        'b': [3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 5, 3, 5, 6]}, 
                  index=range(10))
df.at[df['b'] == 6, 'b'] = np.nan  # np.nan is not special. any float here will produce the same thing.

df
```

This produces (my desired output) in `pandas` versions from 1.2.3 to 1.3.5 (I did not test before 1.2.3):

```
    a    b
0   2  3.0
1   4  4.0
2   1  5.0
3   5  2.0
4  56  NaN
5   6  7.0
6   1  5.0
7   2  3.0
8   1  5.0
9   0  NaN
```

As of version 1.4.0 (and above), the same code produces the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sfleming/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_installs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2273, in __setitem__
    return super().__setitem__(key, value)
  File "/Users/sfleming/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_installs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2228, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, value=value, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "/Users/sfleming/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_installs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3871, in _set_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(index)
  File "/Users/sfleming/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_installs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 388, in get_loc
    self._check_indexing_error(key)
  File "/Users/sfleming/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_installs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5637, in _check_indexing_error
    raise InvalidIndexError(key)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: 0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

Is this a bug?  Should this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at) for versions above 1.4.0:

> Similar to loc, in that both provide label-based lookups. Use at if
> you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or Series.

So what you have to do is change your `at` to `loc`.